# How to implement 1-to-many related post types in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am very new to wordpress. Recently, I need to implement a tour website which has category and tour products. Both have many custom properties as below:
Category: multiple pictures, title, quotes, ...
Tour Product: Pictures, Address, Geolocations, Price, ...

At beginning, I thought taxonomies and post type may work. But found out there is no plugin support custom properties in taxonomies. If I really want to use taxonomies, I probably have to code.

Later, I thought I probably can implement via both post types via plugin of posts to posts.

Anyway, I stuck here, what is the best way in wordpress to implement this common feature?

Thanks, 
Ron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two post types, you can list the items on the second post type (category) on the first using a custom field. [metabox.io](http://metabox.io/) can help you.

Comment: Very good one, thank you very much. sorry for the delay to mark it as an answer, because I just work it out in my project.